# How can I measure differential voltage with ArduinoUNO or UNO32?

Tags: arduino, voltage, pic, temperature, differential

First of all, thank you for your time. I need to measure the differential voltage from the temperature sensor Fluke 80T-IR (infrared temperature probe), I need to do this with an UNO32 or Arduino UNO.

Comment: Get a differential receiver for the specific levels and let it convert the signal to a single-ended.

Comment: The Fluke 80T-IR appears to be a single ended output ....what makes you think you need a differential solution?

Comment: @JackCreasey How would you measure then? I'm thinking that because normally it's measured with a multimeter. Could you explain me? Thanks

Comment: @EugeneSh. I didn't want to use oapams.

Answer (score 1):

The manual for your probe is [here](http://media.fluke.com/documents/80tire__iseng0300.pdf).

Full scale output is 1.000 V = 1000 degF and it's single ended.

The Arduino Uno has a 10 bit A/D and You could simply use the internal 1.1 V reference voltage, that then gives you 1.07 degF per count on the A/D.

You can make the reference voltage what you want of course. I'd suggest you use a 1.024 V reference such as this [Intersil ISL21080](http://www.intersil.com/content/dam/Intersil/documents/isl2/isl21080.pdf).
This will give you 1 degF per count from the A/D.